# How to enforce using pylint human-readable messages?

Tags: pylint

Pylint allows using a string mnemonic when disabling a particular warning and I want to enforce that style in my team, because I deem it way more readable, consider:

```
while True:
# pylint: disable=W0632
# pylint: disable=unbalanced-tuple-unpacking
```

But I cannot find a way to really enforce it as a linter option. Is there any?

Comment: You can modify `.pylintrc` file disabling whatever messages/checkers you wish. Then you just need to put the file in the correct location (same path of your terminal) and run pylint (or use --pylintrc and specify the path)

Comment: I know about pylintrc, I just want to find a way to somehow warn if someone disables error message by code and not by human readable string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I tried to write a custom pylint checker to catch and report exactly that style of comments, I stumbled upon a pylint`s own *informational* checker `use-symbolic-message-instead`, which implements this functionality!

To show this in the output you should add it to `enable` list in the config, for example like this setup.cfg:

```
[pylint]
enable=use-symbolic-message-instead,
```

After enabling, message report looks as

```
************* Module module.py:13:0: I0023: 'W0221' is cryptic: use '# pylint: disable=arguments-differ' instead (use-symbolic-message-instead)
```

Note: However, this does not make pylint exit with non-zero code